# Best way to list all locations in a database ONLY if they are 1km away from the current location?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

The design of my app is that users place a flag on a map and this flag gets its own location and is entered into a database.

When a user opens the app, I want to load a list of all the flags that are ONLY 1km away from them.

I can load all the flags and do an `if` statement to check if the location is 1km away within this for loop, and just append it to the list of flags that will be listed.

How am I able to only list flags that are 1km away without hurting the performance and loading the data of a flag that won't even be added? I'm using Firestore. I don't think this type of querying is possible.

Comment: Firestone does not offer geographic queries, unfortunately. So there is no simple solution for this.

Comment: @VictorPro I do the calculations within the for loop itself to calculate the distance between the current user location and location of the flag. There is no way to do calculation with queries? :(

Comment: @zyne have you tried GeoFirestore? https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-iOS